# What is the name of the set models can be drawn from?

Tags: model-theory

What is the name of the set models can be drawn from? 
For example in propositional calculus an assignment function $v : P \rightarrow \{T,V\}$ can be the model of a formula $a$. What is the (generic) name for the  superset of all models (in this case the set of all functions with the signature $P \rightarrow \{T,V\}$)? Can I call it the domain?

Comment: In first-order logic, if you have a signature $\sigma$, then you would speak of "the class $\sigma$-structures." I do not know the conventions for propositional logic.

Comment: You need to supply a bit more context: what are $P$, $T$ and $V$?